# Queuing the task.Run

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code for Queuing task to read file into result variable.  But sometimes, some files get called together and because of this, the text is stored incorrectly.
How can I make my program wait until a task completes before I run the next foreach?

```
foreach (string path in paths)
{
    result = "";
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
      result = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    }.ContinueWith(x =>
           {
              result = result.remove(25);
           }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

 }
```

Comment: can you use `async/await`? or can you switch to a `IParallelEnumerable`?

Comment: why do you use ContinueWith in this case? just add the line to Run() - unless there is some other code that u are not showing :-)

Comment: @DanielA.White What's different with my code?

Comment: you are just running through creating tasks (and potentially) threads on each iteration.

Comment: @DanielA.White can you give example please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should just turn that around:

```
    result = "";
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (string path in paths)
        {
            result = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        }
    }.ContinueWith(x =>
    {
        result = result.remove(25);
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

not sure what the "remove(25)" is doing, so leaving it at the end, but perhaps that should also move within the foreach loop.